# How to exchange data between two android activities in background to send data via bluetooth?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, bluetooth

I need to pass data from `Activity A` to `Activity B` and backwards in background, because `Activity A` has method, which initializing class, which is managing bluetooth connection, and I cant initialize that class from `Activity B`, because method in Activity A has already initialized it.

I tried to make method that I need to make `static`, but from static method I cant call `non-static` methods from my bluetooth class:

```
   public static void setup(String address) {
            bt = new Bluetooth(this, handler);
            outStringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
            bt.startConn(address);
        //Java throws error that bt is non-static
   }
```

So my questions:

1. Is there a way to call `setup()` from another class when it is `non-static`?
2. And if answer is **YES** how? Or if answer is **NO** How to pass data without calling any methods.

Keep in mind that `startActivityForResult()` or `startActivity()` will not solve this problem, because I need to send data from `Activity B` to `A` many times and `Activity A` should call method from my bluetooth class which sends that data via bluetooth.

**P.S** I found a way with ViewFlipper, but in my case this is too complicated to merge two classes.
And I cant send data directly from `Activity B` to Bluetooth class, because `Activity A` has already opened socket and Java will throw exception that it cant start activity or something like that.

Comment: What type of data are you trying to pass from the activities

Comment: I want to pass String variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK that's very nice...to pass strings from activity 1 to activity 2 you need

**A method to pass  and retrieve this, Intents**

```
public void setUp (String address) {
/* start an intent to pass the string data*/
Intent intent = new Intent(GridViewActivity.this,       MovieDetailActivity.class);

/* use the intent object to pass string to another activity using putExtra method */

intent.putExtra("your string");
 start intent(intent);
}
```

**Then in your receiving activity use getStringExtra**

```
final String original_title =     getIntent().getStringExtra("your string");
```

**then you can use this variable pass from activity using Intent and PutExra and getIntent and getStringExtra methods**

You can google more on this. Passing data from activity using intents.